# Failed to load ApplicationContext java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, microservices, junit5

I am facing problem with JUnit while running unit test cases.I am using JUnit 5. I didn't know why i am getting this exception while running the test code.I tried all the possible ways to execute the code but i got failed to run test cases.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field eventMapperRepository in com.tdchannels.sdk.ms.channel.service.impl.EventServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.tdchannels.sdk.ms.channel.repository.EventMapperRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.tdchannels.sdk.ms.channel.repository.EventMapperRepository' in your configuration.

2020/10/09 16:33:06.617 [Test worker] ERROR o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Request-id :  - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@64fbf401] to prepare test instance [com.tdchannels.sdk.ms.channel.controllers.PaymentChannelControllerV1Test@5cb2e16b]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:337)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:342)
```

Here is my controller

```
@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/v1/sdk/s2s")
@Slf4j
public class PaymentChannelControllerV1 {

    @Autowired
    S2SService s2SService;

    @PostMapping("/payment")
    public ResponseDto createPaymentRequestConversation(@RequestHeader(name = ApplicationConstant.CHANNEL_ID, required = false) String channelId,
                                                        @RequestHeader(name = ApplicationConstant.SERVER_ID, required = false) String serverId,
                                                        @Valid @RequestBody(required = false) Map<String, @Valid RequestDetails> paymentRequestCo) {
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(paymentRequestCo)) return s2SService.getServerHandshakeResponse(serverId);
        RequestDetails requestDetails = (RequestDetails) paymentRequestCo.values().toArray()[0];
        String widgetId = (String) paymentRequestCo.keySet().toArray()[0];
        log.info("Payment create request for user : {} : {}", widgetId, requestDetails);
        return s2SService.savePaymentRequestDetails(widgetId, channelId, requestDetails);

    }
}
```

here is my services class Method

```
@Override
    public ResponseDto savePaymentRequestDetails(String widgetId, String channelId, RequestDetails requestDetails) {
        String userId = requestDetails.getCustomerHash();
        String sdkAccountId = requestDetails.getAccountId();
        log.info("Payment create request for user {} passed : Request Timestamp - {}", userId, requestDetails.getPaymentInitDate());
        log.info("sdkAccountId : {}, channelId : {}, userId : {}", sdkAccountId, channelId, userId);
        UserChannel userChannel = getUserChannelFromPassedParams(sdkAccountId, channelId, userId);
        if (Objects.isNull(userChannel)) {
            log.info("User channel not found. Going to initialize user");
            initializeSdkUser(sdkAccountId, userId);
            userChannel = getUserChannelFromPassedParams(sdkAccountId, channelId, userId);
        }
        storeDataInConversation(userChannel, requestDetails, widgetId);
        return new SuccessResponseDto("Success");
    }
```

here is my Request details class

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class RequestDetails {
    @NotNull
    private String accountId;
    private String message;
    @NotNull
    private String customerHash;
    private String requester;
    @JsonProperty("vpa")
    private String requesterVpa;
    @JsonProperty("txnAmount")
    private String transactionAmount;
    private String formattedAmount;
    private String programId;
    private Long paymentInitDate;
    private Long paymentExpiryDate;
    @NotNull
    private String requestId;
    private String detailPageDeeplink;
    private String detailPageDeeplinkApp;
    private String detailPageDeeplinkPwa;
//  private Map<String, PaymentRequestState> states = RequestState.descriptionRequestStateMap;
    private List<ClickThroughAction> cta;
    private List<Action> action;
    private Map<String, String> additionalParams;
    private Long transactionDate;
    private StatePojo currentState;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String merchantId;
    private String terminalId;
    private String channel;
    private String tranId;
    @JsonProperty("event_type")
    private String eventType;
    
    
}
```

Her is my test case

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"spring.profiles.active=test"},webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {CouchbaseReactiveDataAutoConfiguration.class,
        CouchbaseReactiveRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        CouchbaseDataAutoConfiguration.class, CouchbaseAutoConfiguration.class,
        CouchbaseRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class})
public class PaymentChannelControllerV1Test {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    S2SService s2SService;

    @MockBean
    UserChannelRepository userChannelRepository;

    @MockBean
    WidgetRepository widgetTemplateRepository;

    @MockBean
    S2sServerAccountRepository s2sServerAccountRepository;

    @MockBean
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @MockBean
    UserProfileRepository userProfileRepository;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("restTemplateWithoutLB")
    RestTemplate restTemplateReal;

    @Test
    void testCreatePaymentRequestConversation_success() throws Exception {

        Mockito.when(userChannelRepository.findById(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(Optional.of(new UserChannel()));

        WidgetTemplate widgetTemplate = new WidgetTemplate();
        widgetTemplate.setWidgetType("merchantpay");
        widgetTemplate.setRequester("");
        widgetTemplate.setEncryptedKeys(Stream.of("requester", "requesterVpa").collect(Collectors.toList()));

        Mockito.when(widgetTemplateRepository.findById(Mockito.anyString()))
                .thenReturn(Optional.of(widgetTemplate));

        IntegratorUserProfile integratorUserProfile = new IntegratorUserProfile();
        integratorUserProfile.setEncryptionKey("asdfghjklasdfghj");
        integratorUserProfile.setInitVector("asdfghjklasdfghj");
        Mockito.when(userProfileRepository.findById(Mockito.anyString()))
                .thenReturn(Optional.of(integratorUserProfile));

        mockMvc.perform(
                MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/v1/sdk/s2s/payment").content(TestConstants.PAYMENT_REQUEST_SUCCESS).headers(new HttpHeaders())
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.status").value(1));
    }
}
```

and here is my gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.7.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'jacoco'
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.5" //jacoco version
}

jacocoTestReport {
    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, include: 'com/tdchannels/sdk/**')
        })
    }
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        html.enabled true
        csv.enabled true
    }
}

group = 'com.tdchannels'
version = '2.0.0'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
task printVersion {
    print project.version
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase'
//  compile group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'applicationinsights-web-auto', version: '2.5.0'

    implementation group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'applicationinsights-spring-boot-starter', version: '2.6.0'
    implementation group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'applicationinsights-logging-logback', version: '2.6.0'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation group: 'org.modelmapper', name: 'modelmapper', version: '2.3.8'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-config', version: '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client', version: '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'
    //Version library
    compile group: 'com.github.zafarkhaja', name: 'java-semver', version: '0.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'
//    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'

 // testImplementation('org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.2.0')
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Error clearly states that no bean of type `com.tdchannels.sdk.ms.channel.repository.EventMapperRepository` is not found. Depending on your use case, you can either exclude the configuration which initialises `EventServiceImpl` or mock it.

Comment: Thanks Smile , My problem is solve